# Why does this kind of Recursion work as a return value?

Tags: c, recursion

We use a value `n` to perform recursion on. We save this value in a variable `x`. Then the variable `x` gets added to recursion as a return value. How exactly does this work?

I tried different approaches to check whether you use recursion first for `x` and then use `x` to add it to another recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int up(int n)
{
    int x;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = up(n - 2);
        return x + up(n - 1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
     int n = 20;
     int res;
     res = up(n);
     printf("Result %d\n", res);
     return 0;
}
```

The result is 6765. Since it's a code from school the result should be fine. I just dont get why.

Comment: Why .. wouldn't "it work"? Each recursive function call has a *different* `x` variable in scope, so assignment in each recursive function call has no effect on the caller. The code could also be written as: `return up(n - 2) + up(n - 1);` without any extra variable.

Comment: There's nothing about recursive calls that prevents the result from being assigned to a variable, or adding a variable to the result of a recursive call.

Comment: And it could also be rewritten as `x = up(n-2); y=up(n-1); return x + y`

Comment: It's the same as `return up(n - 2) + up(n - 1)` *except that* it ensures that the `up(n - 2)` term is evaluated first, which the short form does not ensure.  But your `up()` function is pure, so that doesn't make a practical difference.

Comment: Note that you could write `int res = up(n);` in `main()` — or `int res = up(20);`, or even `printf("Result %d\n", up(20));`.

Comment: Note that this would *not* work if `x` were a global variable. But with local variables, each call has its own instance of the variable.

Comment: If up calls itself again with n-2 then what value do we save? Since we start with 20 do we save 18? And then 16? And would it be 19,18,17 and so on for y?

Comment: To understand recursion, I find that it (sometimes) helps to put a print statement at the top of the function, e.g. `printf("calling 'up' with n=%d\n", n);` Note: you might want to start with a smaller value of `n`.

Comment: @Ikaros97 If you call `up(2)`, then when it calls `up(n-2)` it's equivalent to `up(0)`. That returns `0`, so we save `x = 0`

Comment: Then we call `up(n-1)`, which is `up(1)`, it returns `1`, so we `return x + 1`, which is `return 0 + 1`.

Comment: The question is not correctly set, as is. What would be the correct result? What does it do anyway? We can't provide any help if we don't know the requirements of your algorithm. First understand, then look for possible implementation errors.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou There are no errors. This is correct code, he doesn't understand how it works. What it's doing is obvious, it's calculating Fibonacci(n).

Comment: Thanks for tryint to help Barman. The problem is that when i print the result at the end it says 6765. When i do it as you say it starts with up(20-2) = 18. Then 16,14,12 and so on. And even when i try to use it with up(n-1) it never ever adds up to over 6000.

Comment: But he says the result "should" be fine. Is it or not?

Comment: Guys im sorry. Since i know that its about the Fibonacci Series im gonna try understanding it on other websites. Thanks

Comment: You can think of it this way.  When a function calls itself, it's the same as if you made a copy of the function, gave it a different name, and called the copy.  There's really nothing special going on, other than the fact that, as with any function call in C, the new function call gets its own private copy of its local variables.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I think what he meant was "I assume the result is correct, since this code was written by the instructor".

Comment: @Ikaros97 I don't know where you're getting the idea that `up(20-2) = 18`. It seems like you're confusing `x` with `n`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having an issue grasping the concept of the function scope with recursion. It's generally easiest to think of recursion as a tree/stack.

Stack:

Let's say that n=5 for a simplistic example.
Up(5) is pushed onto the stack.
You then declare that x inside of this function scope is UP(3).
Now UP(3) is pushed onto the stack, and UP(5) is waiting for Up(3) to return.
Stack Order:
`Up(3)
Up(5)`

Now Up(3) declares x inside of this function to be UP(1) and patiently waits for Up(1) to return. Since x is declared inside of the function, they are local variables only accessible inside of the function that declared them. This means that the X inside of Up(3) is stored in a completely different location in memory as the X inside of Up(5). You will most definitely learn more about this when you research address-spaces and how local variables are stored and the like. But continuing forward!

Stack:
`Up(1)
Up(3)
Up(5)`

Up(1) returns 1, and thus we pop it off the stack! This means Up(3) can continue running.
Stack:
`Up(3)
Up(5)`

Up(3) now has x=1 (the return of Up(1) and wishes to return x+Up(2). In order to do that we push Up(2) onto the stack.

Stack:
`Up(2)
Up(3)
Up(5)`

Continuing this example, Up(2) will add Up(0) to the stack. Up(0) will return 0 so the x inside of the scope for Up(2) is set to 0. Up(2) will then add Up(1) to the stack, which will return 1. Up(2) will return (0+1). Now we can go back to Up(3) by popping Up(2) off the stack. Up(3) has x=1 and wishes to return (1+1). Popping Up(3) off the stack we are left with Up(5) on the stack. X is now set to 2 due to the return of Up(3). Now we add Up(4) to the stack, which adds Up(2),Up(0),Up(1),Up(3),Up(2),Up(0),Up(1) in that order Note(Many of these calls are popped off before new ones are added).

I recommend reading about global scope and function scope. Understanding these concepts are pretty crucial to the basics of understanding recursion. You can already see however that this type of recursion is pretty bruteforced and not optimized at all. For instance, you are calculating Up(2) multiple times for each recursive call created. This leads to a scalability issue when working with larger numbers, as you are repeating the same operation multiple times on the same number. This can be solved with a memoization array and a bit more logic for a smaller Big O runtime, but that may be a bit too far in detail for this question.

Comment: Thanks alot. Im gonna read up on global and functional scopes. What irritated me most is that there was no for loop. Normally you use that for like i <= 20. In this code we added n-2 +n-1 20 times but i dont know how the decrement works.

Comment: @Ikaros97 No problem! So here you are using recursion in stead of a for loop, a very powerful tool if used correctly. It seems like you have gained somewhat of an understanding of how it works from your comments on other posts, but just picture it this way. When you call UP(20), UP(20) creates a call to UP(18). You are essentially now running another whole function call on UP(18). When UP(18) returns, this value is then set to res inside of UP(20). You make a copy of the function with a smaller N for each up, thus decrementing it and returning at the base cases of n=0 or n=1. LMK if it helped

Comment: Are there some other functions that might help me understand how to use recursion effectively? I heard that the Fibonacci Series is an example for poor use of recursion since it calculates the values waay more often than needed. I heard of the factorial function but thats it.

Comment: You can probably solve any problem utilizing recursion (imo), but it may not be the most effective solution. Recursion can be quite useful when doing graph traversals, like depth-first-search or breadth-first-search. These algorithms also have non-recursive counterparts. The terms of effectiveness all comes down to understanding Big O/Omega/Theta runtimes and utilizing these to evaluate the runtimes of the algorithms you write. Having an understanding of the conceptual-math behind it can be a bit tricky with recurrences, but that is where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

The argument bindings are unique for each call. That means that `n` in `up(20)` is never mixed with the `n` in `up(19)`. Since it is not a reference the `n - 1` is calculated and passed as a new value in a different place the the old so that when it returns the old `n` is what it always has been during the additional calls. Local variables are also only existing in the scope and thus every `x` is different too.

Since this function is pure, thus it's result is the sole product of the algorithm and the argument I think you should go from the base case and up...

The base cases:

```
up(0) => 0
up(1) => 1
```

The default cases:

```
up(2) => up(2-2) + up(2-1) => up(0) + up(1) => 0 + 1
```

Now I knew the results of `0` and `1` from the base cases up there and you can just replace it with the result.  We can go further:

```
up(3) => up(3-2) + up(3-1) => 1 + 1 => 2
up(4) => up(4-2) + up(4-1) => 1 + 2 => 3
up(5) => up(5-2) + up(5-1) => 2 + 3 => 5
...
```

Interesting thing about this (Fibonacci) sequence is that if you have the two previous numbers you can generate the next. This makes this sequence an excellent candidate for either tail recursion or a iterative loop, both of which are far superior to the easier to read recursive version.

Comment: But when does the program know it needs to stop?
Since i used up(n) in main it does it 20 times. But where is it saved?
Normally you use a variable and decrement it like i <= n

Comment: @Ikaros97 When it hits one of the base cases... `up(5) =  up(3) + up(4) = up(1) + up(2) + up(2) + up(3) = up(1) + up(0) + up(1) + up(0) + up(1) + up(1) + up(2) = up(1) + up(0) + up(1) + up(0) + up(1) + up(1) + up(1) + up(0) = 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1+ 1+ 0 = 5` Basically `up(20)` returns `1` 6765 times.

Comment: @Ikaros97 `up(20)` doesn't call `up` 20 times, but `21891` times. Eg. it calls `up(0)` and `up(1)` the most and even `up(5)` is calculated `987` times.

Comment: Thank you every much. I think i somewhat understand it now. When i use up(20) it check whether 20 == 1 or 0. Then it starts to break it down from up(20) to up(18) + up(19). Then it breaks up(18) + up(19) down to up(16) + up(17) + up(17)+up(18). And it keeps doing to until every value is either 0 or 1. And in the end ist just adds the 1's together and returns it. If i remember correctly a function is stored in the stack and when the function is about to end it transfers the "calculated" value to the function that called it.

Comment: @Ikaros97 Correct. Also know that the function applied inside happens to be the same isn't treated specially. It just jumps to the code it represents and it returns back to the point of call and that it happens to be the withing the same function is just coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how much the function could be simplified:

```
int Fib(int n)
{
    return (n<2 ? n : Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2));
}
```

This is simple C, not C++